# /Date(1537909200000)/ I having date formatting issue in 'AngularJS'

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs

I can't display the date in the list in json format. How should I follow a path. My angular js knowledge is not good but I need to use it.

### HtmlPage

```
  <tbody ng-init="GetAllMatches()">
                    <tr ng-repeat="m in filteredlist =(matches.data
                            | filter:filterlist)
                            | orderBy:sort:reverse
                            | pagination: currentPage : numPerPage"
                        ng-if="gamePlayed">
                        <td>{{m.HomeTeamName}}</td>
                        <td>{{m.AwayTeamName}}</td>
                        <td>{{m.StadiumName}}</td>
                        <td>{{m.Referee}}</td>
                        <td>{{m.Weather}}</td>
                        <td>{{ m.StartDate}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

### .netMVC

```
   var matches = await AppService.MatchService.GetMatchesAsync();
        return Json(new { data = matches }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

### JS

```
$scope.GetAllMatches = function () {
    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/Match/GetAllMatchAsync"
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.matches = response.data;
    }, function () {
        alert("error");
    });
};
```

### View

```
/Date(1537909200000)/
```

---

## Solved

I haven't found any information on your problem, but...
As a solution:

> {{m.StartDate.slice(6, -2) | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

Why is your API not returning dates in ISO 8601 format? If you return strings in ISO 8601 format then you just wrap your field function like this

```
function parseISO8601Date(dateStr) {
  return new Date(dateStr); 
}
```

If you really can't change API to return proper ISO 8601 formatted date strings then maybe this blog entry will help you https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates

Here is if link dies

```
if (window.JSON && !window.JSON.dateParser) {
    var reISO = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}(?:\.\d*))(?:Z|(\+|-)([\d|:]*))?$/;
    var reMsAjax = /^\/Date\((d|-|.*)\)[\/|\\]$/;

    JSON.dateParser = function (key, value) {
        if (typeof value === 'string') {
            var a = reISO.exec(value);
            if (a)
                return new Date(value);
            a = reMsAjax.exec(value);
            if (a) {
                var b = a[1].split(/[-+,.]/);
                return new Date(b[0] ? +b[0] : 0 - +b[1]);
            }
        }
        return value;
    };

}

var date = JSON.parse(json,JSON.dateParser);  
console.log(date);
```

Comment: You could override ASP.NET MVC's Json method to use Json.NET instead of Microsoft's serializer to return proper ISO 8601 dates from your API.

Comment: Thanks.I will search